# Speeding up MySQL NOT IN (Subquery)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I'm currently up to try to improve the performance of some of my queries.
As far as I know, statements like "IN" or "NOT IN" are even faster with a large amount of values if a subquery on an indexed field without conditions is used.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 NOT IN (SELECT index_field FROM table2)`

When it comes to use conditions at table2, the query becomes realy slow on a large amount of data.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    field1 NOT IN (
        SELECT
            index_field
        FROM table2
        WHERE
            user_id = '2'
    )
```

I was thinking about using LEFT Join but when I need to to the filtering for the user_id, it also becomes slow.

How may I solve this problem? Currently, I've no clue about that.

Kind regards,

Dominik

//--- EDIT -->

The original query looked sth. like this

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM stream_item si
LEFT JOIN user__publisher_item ui
    ON ui.user_id = 2
    && ui.item_id = si.item_id
INNER JOIN item i
    ON i.id = si.item_id
WHERE 
    si.stream_id IN (5,7,8,9,19,24,29,42,43,44)
    && ui.id IS NULL || (
        ui.`read` = 0 || ui.saved = 1
    )
GROUP BY
    si.item_id
ORDER BY
    si.`found` DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

I have a table which represents the n:m relationship between stream and items.
An unique item can be accessible via multiple streams.
Based upon this i have a state-table for user dependent states of an item.
Currently, the user-state-entry will only be generated, if the item was read or saved the first tim. Otherwise, there is no entry in the user_item table.
In the beginning, this query was fine but now, it takes a lot of time. Even if I leave out the "INNER JOIN" it takes 7 seconds on the current tables with around 500k rows each.

//--- Edit 2 -->
The table-structure in the background is as follows:

- stream
- stream_item //*n:m relation between stream and items*
- item //*unique items*
- stream_group //*user-defined groups of multiple streams*
- stream_group_streams //_n:m relation between stream_groups and streams_
- user
- user_item //*state-table that holds the user-dependent states of an item - if there is no state, no row exists for an item*

btw. sorry for my bad english

Comment: LEFT JOIN ON t2.index_field = t1.field1 WHERE t2.user_id != 2 - is this slow? I think this is the best you can do...

Comment: I'm not sure anybody can provide very meaningful suggestions given that there is very little detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what about `WHERE NOT EXISTS` insetad of NOT IN? are they Same?

Comment: I think EXISTS will be faster because once the engine has found a hit, it will quit looking as the condition has proved true. With IN it will collect all the results from the subquery before further processing

Comment: give me a second, I'll a more detailed query to the main posting

Comment: So - i updated the main post.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT * FROM table1 t1
>
> LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.index_field
>
> WHERE
>
> ```
>    t2.user_id = '2'
> ```

this will be optimized and will serve the purpose! although u can use EXIST as well!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
As Gian suggestet, I provided more details in the main-posting now. Sorry for not doing that before.